# AngularJS: templateUrl is rendering before the controller is free

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below is the code which making some trouble

```
angular.module("cattle_feed_frontend", ['ngResource','ngRoute'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider.
            when('/',
                { 
                    controller: 'FeedController',
                    templateUrl: 'templates/FeedList.html'
                }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });

    }]) 
    .controller('FeedController', function($scope,feeds_factory) {

        $scope.feeds = feeds_factory.allFeeds();
    })
.factory('feeds_factory',['$http', function($http){
return {
    allFeeds : function(){
        $http.get("http://localhost:3000/feeds").then(function(response) 
         {
           return response.data;
         });
    }
}
}])
```

In controller `feeds_factory.allFeeds()` making http call to a 3rd party . now when i see my console . It shows that my template is rendered first and then my `http` is made . Why? and issue due to this behavior is that my template is rendered in which i made the `ng-repeat` which makes nothing because `$scope.feeds` is set after its rendering , as follows

```
<tr ng-repeat="feed in feeds">
    <td>
        {{feed.ingredient}}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{feed.cost_kg}}
    </td>

</tr>
```

Comment: Read about "resolve" in the [documentaion](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) and this [tutorial](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx) it allows you to get the data before the state change

Comment: What does your feeds_factory look like? You might be calling a promise and you likely need to say feeds_factory.allFeeds().when(....)

Comment: Show us the code for `feeds_factory`.allFeeds`? If it is making an http call, then I suspect it is asynchronous and not actually returning a list of feeds.

Answer (score 2):

Because `$routeProvider` doesn't know your controller is going to make a http request, it doesn't know to wait. To tell it you use the `resolve` property of a route:

```
$routeProvider.
    when('/',
        { 
            controller: 'FeedController',
            templateUrl: 'templates/FeedList.html',
            resolve: {
                feeds: function(feeds_factory) {
                    return feeds_factory.allFeeds();
                }
            }
        }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
```

Then return the promise from `feeds_factory`:

```
factory('feeds_factory',['$http', function($http){
    return {
        allFeeds : function(){
            return $http.get("http://localhost:3000/feeds").then(function(response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        }
    }
}])
```

Then inject into the controller:

```
controller('FeedController', function($scope, feeds) {
    $scope.feeds = feeds;
})
```

Comment: your suggestion made template render after the http request , which was the original question , but it's giving undefined feeds in controller , while the feeds are present in response ?

Comment: i marked it as not an answer because i checked that feeds even in routers are undefined . sorry for that

Comment: Your `allFeeds` function needs to return the http promise: `allFeeds : function() { return $http.get... }`

Comment: it's making http request and returning data but in resolve it's not

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you need to change your code to this:

```
.controller('FeedController', function($scope,feeds_factory) {

    feeds_factory.allFeeds()
        .then(function(feeds) {
            $scope.feeds = feeds;
        });
})
```